# Solr + Jelastic access URL

Tags: url, solr, jetty, jelastic

I have Solr deployed in Jelastic with Jetty. Its admin page can be accessed with the URL:

```
http://mydomain.jelastic.servint.net/solr
```

But when I try to add a document from another machine like this:

```
String urlString = "http://mydomain.jelastic.servint.net/solr";
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
document.addField("id", "552199");
document.addField("name", "Gouda cheese wheel cheese");
UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest();
req.add(document);
UpdateResponse response = req.process(solr);
```

It does not work. I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Server at http://mydomain.jelastic.servint.net/solr returned non ok status:411, message:Length Required
```

If I use a fake URL it returns the same error, so I think the root cause must be a problem with the URL.
It works fine accessing Solr at the same machine.

Could anybody give me a hand?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same question. and resolved.
the reason is nginx under 1.3.9 is not support HttpChunkinModule。 
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpChunkinModule

Answer (score 0):

It can also require [Public IP](http://jelastic.com/docs/public-ipv4) for your Jetty app server. Because by default all requests go through global Resolver and it can also restrict your actions.